# Powermock to mock instance methods called from other executing methods

Tags: mockito, powermock

In this code, i have mocked the one of the ValidateHandlerSoapClient class method which is instantiated and  called this method (soapClientSpy.processSoapRequestRespons) in validateMsisdnHandlerIRSpy.validate().So soapClientSpy.processSoapRequestResponse is not working , instead the real method is called.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ValidateMsisdnHandler.class,ValidateHandlerSoapClient.class})
public class Demo {

    MessageControl messageControl=PowerMockito.mock(MessageControl.class);
    Validate validate=PowerMockito.mock(Validate.class);
    ValidateMsisdnHandlerIR  validateMsisdnHandlerIRSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new ValidateMsisdnHandlerIR());
    ValidateHandlerSoapClient soapClientSpy = PowerMockito.spy( new ValidateHandlerSoapClient());



    @Before
    public void initialize() throws Exception
    {

        PowerMockito.when(validate.getAccountId()).thenReturn("0879221485");
         PowerMockito.doReturn(true).when(validateMsisdnHandlerIRSpy, "isPrePaid",anyString());
         MemberModifier.field( ValidateMsisdnHandlerIR.class, "endDate").set(
                validateMsisdnHandlerIRSpy, "10-FEB-2015");

        PowerMockito.when(soapClientSpy.processSoapRequestResponse(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
         PowerMockito.whenNew(ValidateHandlerSoapClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(soapClientSpy);

    }

    @Test
    public void testValidateMsisdn_Cr6_Roverprempay_Not_Roverpayg() throws Exception{

    Response response = validateMsisdnHandlerIRSpy.validate(validate,messageControl);

    }
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, when `validateMsisdnHandlerIRSpy.validate` is called, a new instance of `ValidateHandlerSoapClient` is created inside that method?

Comment: yes and then it calls soapClientSpy.processSoapRequestResponse(string) method. Pls help me !

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`ValidateHandlerSoapClient soapClientSpy = PowerMockito.spy( new ValidateHandlerSoapClient())`

with

`ValidateHandlerSoapClient soapClientMock = PowerMockito.mock(ValidateHandlerSoapClient.class)`

A spy by default just calls the methods of the underlying regular class. What you want to do is (presumably) nothing when the methods of the soap client are called.

Then of course you will need to make also change:

PowerMockito.whenNew(ValidateHandlerSoapClient.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(soapClientMock);

Comment: Before posting I have tried this way & its not working. Pls help me