# How to use Mockito when we cannot pass a mock object to an instance of a class

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose I have a class like that:

```
public class MyClass {

    Dao dao;

    public String myMethod(Dao d) {

        dao = d;

        String result = dao.query();

        return result;
    } 
}
```

I want to test it with mockito. So I create a mock object and I call the method to test in that way:

```
Dao mock = Mockito.mock(Dao.class);

Mockito.when(mock.myMethod()).thenReturn("ok");

new MyClass().myMethod(mock);
```

But, suppose instead I have a class like that:

```
public class MyClass {

    Dao dao = new Dao();

    public String myMethod() {

        String result = dao.query();

        return result;
    } 
}
```

Now I cannot pass my mock as an argument, so how I gonna test my method? Can someone show an example?

Comment: Reflection or you'd need to use some instrumentation I believe . That one of the reasons Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection are so popular. They make testing very easy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: Have a look at reflection - it's great for testing, and it allows you to set any field of a class.

Comment: Use PowerMockito, stuff like MockConstructor, @PrepareForTest, etc., e.g., https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor, http://stackoverflow.com/q/25160761/438992, https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13, etc.

Comment: @user1883212 - Do you have the option of modifying MyClass? If so then Dependency Injection is a good option as mentioned in the first 2 comments.  If not, then Dave Newton's suggestion of using PowerMockito is an option.

Answer (score 13):

Fundamentally, you're trying to replace a private field with an alternative implementation, which means you'd violate encapsulation. Your only other option is to restructure the class or method, to make it better-designed for testing.

There are a lot of short answers in the comments, so I'm aggregating them here (and adding a couple of my own) as Community Wiki. *If you have any alternatives, please feel free to add them here.*

### Restructure the class

- Create a setter for the field in question, or relax the field's visibility.
- Create a dependency-injecting override or static method that takes a DAO, and make the public instance method delegate to it. Test the more-flexible method instead.

  ```
  public String myMethod() { return myMethod(dao); }
  String myMethod(Dao dao) { /* real implementation here */ }
  ```
- Add a constructor overload or static factory method that replaces private fields for the sake of testing.
- Fully structure the class for [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection). ([Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis), [EJK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072150/ejk))

Note that some of these can be package-private for testing, if you put your tests in the same Java package (possibly in a separate source tree). In all cases, good names and documentation are helpful to make your intentions clear.

### Violate encapsulation

- Use reflection to set private fields in the class. ([kinbiko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422278/kinbiko) - see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552734/1426891))
- Use [PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects) to replace the `Dao` constructor with a mock of your choice. ([Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton))

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
public class MyClassTest {

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    Dao dao = Mockito.mock(Dao.class);

    public void testMyMethod() {

        Field field = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("dao");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(myClass, dao);
        //Do the test...
    } 
}
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments this assumes that you don't change the name of the `dao` field. It might be a good idea then to get all the fields, `Field[] fields = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();` and iterate over them, getting the field(s) of type Dao. Then proceeding as above. This way your test doesn't depend on the name of your field anymore.

Comment: Not a bad approach, but has the obvious limitation that if the name of the field ever changes, the compiler will not catch this.  This test would then fail at runtime.