# Capture Arguments from Chained Methods Using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm writing some Java unit tests for an existing class using Mockito. However, I'm having trouble extracting the arguments with which an object of this class is calling a method as part of a nested call.

Example:

```
public class SomeClass {

  public SomeClass() {
    //...
  }

  public someMethod(Foo foo) {
    // Bar bar = ...
    someOtherMethod(bar);
  }

  private someOtherMethod(Bar bar) {
    //...
  }
}
```

I want to capture the arguments to `someOtherMethod()` and verify that `bar` is what it should be. Can I do this using `ArgumentCaptor` or other functionality within Mockito?

Comment: Does someOtherMethod call a method on another class?

Comment: @EricF: yes it does. I will capture at that boundary instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mocking `someOtherMethod` is unlikely to provide you a useful result.* `someMethod` is part of your public API, but `someOtherMethod` is not; in general, it's important to test the contract (someMethod's return value and side effects) but it's an antipattern to test the implementation (the private methods that someMethod calls).

- Ideally, just test the results and side-effects of `someMethod`, and consider its implementation a black box. You probably won't even need to use Mockito for this. This is the purest form of test-driven development: it frees you to refactor `someMethod`, maybe entirely omitting calls to `someOtherMethod` or caching the result (etc) without editing your test.
- If `someOtherMethod` calls an external service, make it an accessible or settable field on your SomeClass instance and mock that service instead.
  Interactions with other services could reasonably be considered part of a general contract; this is really what Mockito was designed for.
- If `someOtherMethod` is independent enough that you want to test `someMethod` separately, consider making it package-private or protected. That way you can override it with a dummy implementation in your test, and possibly elsewhere in your code—after all, it's now a tested part of your `someMethod` contract, right? You can also consider making it a separate mockable class, if it's that big or opaque.

See also ["How do I unit test private methods?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods) in Programmers.SE, or ["How to use Mockito when we cannot pass a mock object to an instance of a class"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27552499/1426891) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to override SomeClass with a class that stores those arguments and makes them available to you for verification.  An elegant option is [custom argument matchers](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html).

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

```
@Spy
private SomeClass someClassSpy;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Bar> barCaptor;

...

verify(someClassSpy).someOtherMethod(barCaptor.capture());
Bar bar = barCaptor.getValue();
assertThat(bar, is(...));
```