# Mockito NullPointerException while using any

Tags: mockito, junit4

I am trying to use Mockito like this :

```
    Mockito.when(Mockito.any(ObjectMapper.class).readValue(Mockito.any(BufferedReader.class),Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(new Person("1","abc"));
```

This is from Jackson library .

```
public <T> T readValue(Reader src, Class<T> valueType)
```

The reason I am doing it is because the time I reach this point of the code there are a ton of objects which were created. Mocking on every step would take time.

Any reason why I am getting NPE when code reaches this mockito statement?

Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.prashant.flax.ShellTest.givenDirectoryHasFiles(ShellTest.java:139)
    at com.prashant.flax.ShellTest.testExecute(ShellTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

As you can see it is in a given method(this method only has this piece of code) , so I can see while debugging, it reaches over there and crashes.

Comment: add stacktrace of your NPE

Comment: You have to stub on a specific mock object - I don't believe you can do `when(any(T.class)....)`.

Comment: That's my guess as well. But compiler is not complaining, hence I thought let me ask.

Comment: "Compiler doesn't complain" != "my code is fine" ;).  Also, your stacktrace doesn't involve Mockito at all...

Comment: Thanks @OliverCharlesworth . Yeah I am not sure why there is no mockito, but it does fail over there. At least according to intellij(ShellTest.java:139 is that line). But anyway if this is not the way to go. I'll find some other way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Oliver mentioned in the comments, you can't apply `when` to happen to all objects. Mockito works via subclassing, so you have to create a mock instance using `mock`, `spy`, or a `@Mock` or `@Spy` annotation; customize the behavior; and then install the mock [using dependency injection or other similar tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27552499/1426891).

---

As to *why* this happens, the return value for `any()` actually is `null`; matchers like `any` are only supposed to be used as arguments to `when` and `verify`, and Mockito can't produce a specialized instance of `Class` that represents "any Class", so Mockito returns a dummy value (null) and stores data on a specialized stack of argument matchers. Though Mockito has better error messages to alert you to this situation, your code NPEs before Mockito can give you a proper exception with usage examples.

For more about matcher return values and the stack, see my other SO answer on ["How do Mockito matchers work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

Comment: Thanks Jeff. That helped. I'll save that other Q.

Answer (score 2):

For me the actual problem was that I was trying to mock a spy. When mocking a spy you have to use the `doReturn` or `doAnswer` methods. Otherwise the method of the spy will be actually called while trying to mock it and unexpected behavior can happen. E.g. when calling `when` with `any()`, `any()` will just return `null`. So it is likely that you will get an `NullPointerException`.

Here is a full example that demonstrates the bahavior:

```java
package com.company;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class SpyTest {

    public class Controller {
        public String method(String arg) {
            return arg.substring(0, 1);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void withMockTest() {
        Controller controllerMocked = mock(Controller.class);
        when(controllerMocked.method(anyString())).thenReturn("42");
        assertEquals("42", controllerMocked.method("FOO"));
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void withSpyWhenThenReturnBreakingBecauseMethodToBeMockedIsActuallyBeingCalled() {
        Controller controllerSpied = spy(new Controller());
        when(controllerSpied.method(any())).thenReturn("42");
    }

    @Test
    public void withSpyDoReturnWhen() {
        Controller controllerSpied = spy(new Controller());
        doReturn("42").when(controllerSpied).method(any());
        assertEquals("42", controllerSpied.method("FOO"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on what @jeff-bowman said in his answer, any() returns null, so if you need something that doesn't return null, you can try this:

```
/**
 * never returns null
 */
private inline fun <reified T> any(type: Class<T>): T = Mockito.any(type)

/**
 * returns null
 */
private inline fun <reified T> any(): T = Mockito.any<T>()
```