# Mock a method which is called from multiple methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

So my code looks something like this

```
class One
{
   private final Two two;
   public One()
   {
       two = new Two(this)
   }
   public void method1()
   {
       //do something
       method2();
   }
   public void method2()
   {
       //do something
       two.method3();
    }
}

class Two
{
    private final One one;
    public Two(One one)
    {
        this.one=one;
     }
    public void method3()
    {
        //print something
    }
}
```

Now, i'd like to mock method3() in class Two while i test method1() of class One and my Junit is like this.

```
private One one;
private Two two;
@Before
public void setup()
{
    one = Mockito.spy(new One());
    two = Mockito.spy(new Two(one));
}
    

@Test
pubic void testMethod1InClassOne()
{
    Mockito.doNothing().when(testTwo).method3();
    testOne.method1();
}
```

But somehow, method3() is not getting mocked and i'm still seeing the contents its printing. However, i can successfully mock method2(). maybe because method2() is directly called from method1() which is the method i am testing? Please suggest how can i mock method3.

Thanks,
Meher

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Make `testOne` testable by injecting `testTwo` in it.

`two` object seems to be the instance member of the instance of `One` class. Therefore it needs to be mocked(or it's behaviour to be stubbed) to achieve your goal.
In `testMethod1InClassOne` test method you did not inject mocked `testTwo` object into `testOne` object so even Mockito accepts the stubbing on the following line it does not replace it with actual call, as those happen on **different instances**. What is more, it seems objects of class `One` are not testable, I would recommend you to add the following constructor to the class definition:

```
One(Two two) {
   this.two = two;
}
```

And then your test might looks like this:

```
@Test
pubic void testMethod1InClassOne()
{
    Two testTwo = Mockito.mock(Two.class);
    One testOne = new One(testTwo);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(testTwo).method3();
    testOne.method1();
}
```

Comment: +1. I have a [community wiki answer of other strategies as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27552499/1426891), but the refactor you described is probably the strongest and most appropriate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But in my code, class Two has a parameterized constructor with class One object as an argument and i have injected mocked One one object in Two constructor as well. It still doesn't work. Have updated my question properly now. please suggest what to do now and where i am doing wrong.