# Regular unit tests pass but Mockito all fail

Tags: mocking, mockito

this simple mockito is failing I do not know why? I suspect set up is not complete?
When I replace userService  by userDAO in the test method it passes, why this happen?

```
public class UserServiceTest {

private static IUserService userService;
private static IUserDAO userDAO;

private User GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1;


@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    userService = new UserService();
    userDAO = mock(IUserDAO.class);
    
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    
    GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1 = new User(1, "genericEmployee1", "genericPassword", Role.EMPLOYEE);
   
  }

@Test
public void testGetByUsernamePassesWhenUsernameExists() {
    //Optional<User> u=userDAO.create(GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1);
    //assertEquals(u.get().getUsername(),"genericEmployee1");
   when(userDAO.getByUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1));

    assertEquals(Optional.of(GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1),
            userService.getByUsername(GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1.getUsername()));

    verify(userDAO).getByUsername(GENERIC_EMPLOYEE_1.getUsername());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't installing your mock `userDAO` into your real `userService` anywhere; your `userDAO` represents a single mocked instance, not a stand-in for every IUserDAO in your test.

In order for your tested `userService` to use your mocked `userDAO`, you may have to accept a `userDAO` (or any other IUserDAO instance) as a constructor argument in UserService. This kind of refactor would allow a system that uses UserService (e.g. production or your test) to manage or *inject* UserService's *dependencies*, rather than letting UserService create or control its own dependencies. This general technique is "Dependency Injection" or "Inversion of Control", but for something as small and immediate as this you don't need a framework or container that manages dependency injection for you. If you are unable to make a change like this, you can pursue [one of several alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27552499/1426891).

Where before you might have had:

```java
public class UserService implements IUserService {
  private final IUserDao userDao;

  public UserService() {
    this.userDao = new UserDAO();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Instead, try this:

```java
public class UserService implements IUserService {
  private final IUserDao userDao;

  public UserService() {
    this(new UserDAO());
  }

  /* package private for testing */
  UserService(IUserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

This will then let you install your mock UserDAO into your real UserService:

```java
@BeforeClass // see side note
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    userDAO = mock(IUserDAO.class);   
    userService = new UserService(userDAO);
}
```

As a side note, it will be much easier to understand your tests if you instantiate your `userService` and `userDAO` in a `@Before` method instead of `@BeforeClass`, as this will prevent any test's setup from interfering in any other test. You may also look into [MockitoJUnitRunner or MockitoRule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10806345/1426891) for additional automation of your test setup.

Comment: thanks Jeff. I tried every combination of userService=mock(userDAO) /userService=mock(IUserService.classs) ...etc . please can you show how to mock userService. I learn by example rather than by concept

Comment: @kobosh No, because you should not want to mock UserService when your test is trying to prove UserService's correctness. You should be setting up a real UserService with possibly-mocked dependencies like UserDAO so you can confirm UserService's behavior and interactions without a real database and without ensuring UserDAO is bug-free.

Comment: thanks Jeff. userService=mock(userDAO) gives error: Description Resource Path Location Type
The method mock(Class<T>) in the type Mockito is not applicable for the arguments (IUserDAO) UserServiceTest.java. I don't know what/where to mockUserService. can you please show me

Comment: @kobosh I've edited my example, but I am very concerned that you are still trying to mock UserService. You should not be trying to do that, and under no circumstance will mock(UserDAO.class) produce anything that resembles a UserService.

Comment: Sorry I missed to see yoyr post in  its integrity. let me try it and come to you.